# Hint text is not visible in login_fresh package of flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show hint text over the input box in flutter. And I did not find any hint key related to this package. It is neither visible on the login nor the sign-up page.

```
LoginFresh buildLoginFresh() {
    List<LoginFreshTypeLoginModel> listLogin = [
      LoginFreshTypeLoginModel(
          callFunction: (BuildContext _buildContext) {
            // develop what they want the facebook to do when the user clicks
          },
          logo: TypeLogo.facebook),
      LoginFreshTypeLoginModel(
          callFunction: (BuildContext _buildContext) {
            // develop what they want the Google to do when the user clicks
          },
          logo: TypeLogo.google),
      LoginFreshTypeLoginModel(
        callFunction: (BuildContext _buildContext) {
          Navigator.of(_buildContext).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_buildContext) => widgetLoginFreshUserAndPassword(),
            ),
          );
        },
        logo: TypeLogo.userPassword,
      ),
    ];

    return LoginFresh(
      pathLogo: 'assets/images/horario.jpg',
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.black,
      isExploreApp: false,
      functionExploreApp: () {
        // develop what they want the ExploreApp to do when the user clicks
      },
      isFooter: false,
      widgetFooter: widgetFooter(),
      typeLoginModel: listLogin,
      isSignUp: true,
      widgetSignUp: widgetLoginFreshSignUp(),
    );
  }
```

[Click here is view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQFX9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your LoginFreshUserAndPassword with the Theme widget like this :

```
Theme(
data: ThemeData(hintColor: Colors.red),
child: LoginFreshUserAndPassword(),
)
```

it should work now.

Comment: Hint text is already defined in login_fresh package (https://pub.dev/packages/login_fresh). So, where should I change?

Comment: do you have any white color in your theme?

Comment: I've changed the answer you can check now.